# java script slide show is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Now i am learning html,css and javascript.

Now i am working with html,css and javascript slideshow.

Here is the code for slideshow: Javascript

```
 $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
```

And call js file in html like this:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" src= "js/slide.js"></script>
```

But images shows orderly, slideshow did not work.my page look like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOM2g.jpg

May i know, what is my mistake?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does js/slide.js contain? Did you include jQuery? Can you create a fiddle to illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

you missed the-child in this line

```
 $('#slideshow > img:first')
```

```js
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();
setInterval(function() { 
      $('#slideshow > div:first-child')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    },  3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/1" width="200" height="200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/2" width="200" height="200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/3" width="200" height="200"/></div>
  <div><img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/sports/4" width="200" height="200"/></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle?.. because  did not work for me. thanks